# Using VBA in MS Access to import and update xlsx files into data table automatically

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

I found this code on stack overflow and tweaked it to fit my needs, I am trying to get it to take all files that come into this folder called archive and transfer the data from each file into the data table I have set up in Access called Archive Data, I need to make this process automatic, as files are added to this file regularly, as of now you have to manually run the macro, I need it to be automatic, I am not sure how to go about that, any suggestions?

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Function DoImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 blnHasFieldNames = False


 strPath = "U:\CSV\Archive\"


strTable = "Archive Data"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
   strPathFile = strPath & strFile
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
         strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames



   strFile = Dir()
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Seems you are missing a slash.  What happens with this change? `strPath = "U:\CSV\Archive\"`

Comment: @HansUp the debug is saying that external table is not in expected format.

Comment: You need to enable the `strFile = Dir()` line if you intend to loop through all the matching files.

Comment: OK.  Is the external file actually a CSV text file or is it an Excel workbook file?  Use `TransferSpreadsheet` for a workbook, `TransferText` for a text file.

Comment: the file is a excel worksheet saved as an CSV file

Comment: [DoCmd.TransferText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx)

Comment: It sounds like the script works and you want to run it without intervention. You can run the code based on a timer event.  Please see this link.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

I am wondering about the concept though.  Don't you want to run the code when you know there is a change in the data, but not just based on a time interval.  If you do the latter, I think you'll quickly end up with dupes if the data hasn't been updated and you run the loading process.

Comment: @ryguy7272 yea the time interval could work, what I need to happen is  whenever data is added to the excel spreadsheet access knows to take that information and put it into a database. Something like a copy and paste method or a transfer method. I am writing this code in vba so our manufacturing staff can easily enter the data in excel and not worry about clicking a button or doing any computer work. I have tried several methods with no luck.

Comment: OK, given this setup, I'd recommend using a Worksheet_Change event to trigger the start.  Do a little Googling on this.  When the Worksheet changes, an event fires.  I think you should do some kind of comparison in Excel; maybe delete dupes, or something along those lines.  Let Excel clean the data and prepare the data for delivery to Access.  Then run the Windows Scheduler once per day, maybe around 9pm or 10pm, when everything that should have been done for the day has been done at that point.  I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to consider, is the possibility of checking the time stamp of files, to see what files have been changes.  This is a 'file watcher' of sorts.  VB.NET and C#.NET have much more evolved ways of doing this, but if you are operating only in the VBA world, you can consider something like this.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/528653-visual-basic-applications-file-watcher-possible.html